# best solution to store data temporarily (2h max) read/write access

Tags: android, database, google-cloud-messaging

I have an Android application and I want the users to be able to create some kind of "rooms" and let their friends also join (thanks to a password or w/e).
So basically, I need to store few data:

- id of the room
- password
- data which can be read and modify by all members of the "room"

Those data can be erase after 2 hours.
Is there any solution other than create a classic database on my server ? 
A sqlite database store of the user "host" ? 
I read a bit about google cloud message but I don't think it will fit in my case.

Thank you !

Comment: What is a "room"? What does it mean to "join"? If you are borrowing terms from online chats, and that is the model that you are following, where exactly do the rooms exist? How is your app communicating with whatever powers the rooms? Once you have those questions answered, the answer to "where is the data stored" should become apparent.

Comment: @CommonsWare I meant "room" just put a word on "private data that only few people can access"
That was not very clear, my bad.
I just need my app to get and put data somewhere.

For example with a relationnal database, I would just have a table like this :
id   /    password    /   relevant data
The user of the application with the correct id/password could access and modify those data (through a php server for exemple).
Before implementing this solution, I would like to know if there is something else knowing that I do not need to store those data for more than 2 hours.

Comment: "I just need my app to get and put data somewhere" -- yes, but you are implying that the "somewhere" is a place that multiple apps can reach. This would seem to be a very central element of your app. Either you already know what sort of communications you are going to use, or you do not. If you do, please edit your question and explain where the rooms are and how the app will communicate with them. Data storage will become much more obvious once you know how you are communicating amongst these friends.